# How to add zoom in effect to a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, zoom

I'm working in a project where I should generate a video, from an input set of videos or images.

The problem is when I generate the video I must add a zoomin effect to each input element.

I solved the problem with images in this way (I repeat this command for each image):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i test.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -t 5 -s "796x450" test.mp4
```

And after I concat the generated videos.

Now, I trying the same solution for videos, but without success. 
Should I convert before the video in images? Or there's another way?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**

This is the command I use for videos.

```
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:s=640x360" -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -y smallzoom.mp4ffmpeg version 2.3.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  7 2014 18:14:20 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/stuzzo/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/stuzzo/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/stuzzo/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/stuzzo/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 98.100 / 52. 98.100
  libavcodec     55. 72.102 / 55. 72.102
  libavformat    55. 51.101 / 55. 51.101
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.102 /  4. 11.102
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'small.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300
  Duration: 00:00:05.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 551 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 560x320, 465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'smallzoom.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.51.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
      encoder         : Lavc55.72.102 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 104 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
      encoder         : Lavc55.72.102 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[output stream 0:0 @ 0x30671a0] 100 buffers queued in output stream 0:0, something may be wrong.
frame=  175 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=     244kB time=00:00:05.76 bitrate= 346.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=20575    
video:165kB audio:71kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.131025%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.98  size: 20122
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] frame P:46    Avg QP:21.52  size:  2151
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] frame B:128   Avg QP:25.80  size:   385
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] consecutive B-frames:  2.3%  0.0%  1.7% 96.0%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] mb I  I16..4: 46.3% 27.6% 26.1%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] mb P  I16..4:  1.8%  0.4%  0.1%  P16..4: 37.3%  7.8%  5.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:46.8%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 22.7%  1.1%  0.2%  direct: 0.4%  skip:75.5%  L0:45.0% L1:52.6% BI: 2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] 8x8 transform intra:25.2% inter:68.0%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 29.7% 62.3% 31.5% inter: 2.9% 9.0% 1.4%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] i16 v,h,dc,p:  0% 30%  1% 69%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 30% 17%  4%  6%  4% 13%  4%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 30%  9%  4%  8%  6% 13%  4%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 40%  9%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] ref P L0: 61.2%  5.1% 22.5% 11.1%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] ref B L0: 82.0% 13.6%  4.4%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] ref B L1: 94.0%  6.0%
[libx264 @ 0x3066180] kb/s:230.91
```

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do this in terminal? Is installing OpenShot not an option? If I remember correctly, there's an option in OpenShot, an effect which lets you pan and zoom on the video. And you can also composite images into video much more easily... Or are you doing this on Windows? I assumed it wasn't Windows because you're using ffmpeg...

Comment: What command did you try for videos? What was the console output?

Comment: @zorvalent I'm in a web project and I need a command line tool. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rajib I edited my answer. ffmpeg generates a new video, but no zoom effect is added.

Comment: Hm. `ffplay test.mp4 -vf "scale=640:360, zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125"` works for me, while the same using `ffmpeg` gives a 1280x720 output. When I use the scale filter like you I get the same buggy behavior. Maybe we should post another bug report. Have to investigate more. Also try asking on https://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user

Answer (score -1):

Here's a command to do it all in one command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i image1jpg -loop 1 -i image2.jpg -loop 1 -i image3.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5,scale=796x450,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5,scale=796x450,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[2:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5,scale=796x450,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; [v0][v1][v2] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0, format=yuv420p[v]" -map '[v]' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -q:v 1 test.mp4
```

Comment: This would be much, *much* better if you explain how the proposed command works!